# Windows mail will only save attachement

Tags: windows-10, windows-mail

On one of my Windows 10 computers, Windows Mail will not allow me to open directly an attachment. On double click, the save dialogue appears. On right click and open, the save dialogue appears.

I want to be able to directly open attachments (I know it saves in a temporary folder, that's not the point).

There are plenty posts on the Microsoft forums discussing this. I am not posting them here so no one is tempted to waste time going over them, but Google will list a graveyard of dead ends.

This is not ubiquitous behavior. One possible related piece of information is that I have McAfee DLP Endpoint and McAfee Management of Native Encryption installed on said computer - I must keep these, so if these are the reason for the problem it would be useful to stop my search (I can't uninstall to check).

I also have no problem changing

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Files\S0
```

which is where my working computer saves temporary attachments.

Comment: This indicates a permission problem on the location of the temporary file that would be created.  The fact you have Enterprise security and encryption software installed I would get your Administrator involved.  This isn’t an issue you can solve as a non-Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound that's a good point. We often have defaults that can be changed, not everything though - so there is a chance. Do you have a suggestion on how to diagnose this? Where the temporary file is being created, a log for Windows mail? If I can verify this that is a valid answer to my question.

Comment: It should be the same temporary directory as Outlook uses, but since we are dealing with a UWP application, it might be the AppData directory.  *I don't honestly know, but it doesn't matter, your user doesn't have permissions to that directory otherwise a temporary file would be created and it would be opened.*  You can use one of the working PCs to determine the location though, open a document then use "save as", you should be able to determine the directory of the file that is created.

Comment: @Ramhound did that - I have no problem adding directories to that location, or files

Comment: Get your Administrator involved.

Comment: I talked to the techies, and they say to leave the laptop for a few days. Since they don't know, and I'm not the only one on the internet with this problem, I'll leave this in case someone figures it out.